# How to avoid duplications messages in RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq

Is it possible to avoid sending the same messages (data) to the certain queue using RabbitMQ configuration?
Or should I do this programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RabbitMQ does not offer message de-duplication out of the box.

There is a [plugin](https://github.com/noxdafox/rabbitmq-message-deduplication) which offers a certain level of de-duplication.

You can also implement de-duplication yourself at either the producers or consumers by checking if the sent/received message was already seen against a cache.